# Getting deprecated warning while getting the height, width in android for Api >= 30 and Api < 30 even after enclosing the code in if else block

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-api-levels

After going through some stack overflow questions, I have written the code to get the height and width in Android for *Api level >= 30* and *Api level < 30* below :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val backgroundThread = Thread {

        val metric: WindowMetrics
        val insets: Insets    // An Insets instance holds four integer offsets which describe changes to the four edges of a Rectangle.
        val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics
        val width: Int
        val height: Int
        val insetsWidth: Int
        val insetsHeight: Int

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

            // Code for API level 30 and higher

            metric = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
            insets = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility (WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars() or WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout ())

            insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left
            insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom

            Log.d ("tally", "${insets.right}, ${insets.left}, ${insets.top}, ${insets.bottom}")

            width = metric.bounds.width () - insetsWidth
            height = metric.bounds.height () - insetsHeight

        } else {

            displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics ()
            windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics (displayMetrics)

            width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
            height = displayMetrics.heightPixels
        }
    }
    backgroundThread.start()
}

/**
 * A native method that is implemented by the 'dpi_poc' native library,
 * which is packaged with this application.
 */
external fun stringFromJNI(): String

companion object {
    // Used to load the 'dpi_poc' library on application startup.
    init {
        System.loadLibrary("dpi_poc")
    }
}
```

}

I'm not able to understand why I'm still getting the deprecated warning, as shown in the image below, even after enclosing the code in if else block.

[image]

What's wrong in the above code and how to solve this warning and write code to get the height and width in android for both api level >= 30 and api level < 30?

Comment: I don't think the code is wrong. It's just a warning. I think you could annotate the method with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` to remove it maybe

Comment: Code is ok. Just tested and it's **not** warning me with deprecation. Can't reproduce it.

Comment: Can you post your whole code ?

Comment: @ItzDavi, have posted the whole code except the import statements.

Comment: Please if you can post also your imports, manifest and gradles files it could help.

Comment: BTW the compiler will not run your code, that is, it does not matter if there is an `if-else` checking the version - it will always compile both blocks (the `if` one and the `else` one)

Comment: ( unless the condition is a compile time constant )